# Properly inject AuthManager?

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am using [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) library, which injects AuthManager using type-hinting:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager;
class Basic extends Authorization
{

public function __construct(AuthManager $auth, $identifier = 'email')
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->identifier = $identifier;
    }
```

The problem is that if I used the middleware jwt.auth:

```
app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router')->version('v1', ['middleware' => ['jwt.auth'] , 'prefix' => 'api', 'providers' => ['jwt']], function ($api) {
    $api->get('protected', function () {

       $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
       return $token;
    });
});
```

I get this error:

```
{"message":"Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $app ]] in class Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthManager","status_code":500,"debug":{"line":839,"file":"\/share\/vendor\/illuminate\/container\/Container.php","class":"Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException"
```

So, the question is, how to properly inject the AuthManager ? why $app was not resolved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try injecting `AuthManager` in your `bootstrap/app.php` file:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Service Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will register all of the application's service providers which
| are used to bind services into the container. Service providers are
| totally optional, so you are not required to uncomment this line.
|
*/

$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);

// Injecting goes here
$app->singleton(Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::class, function ($app) {
    return $app->make('auth');
});
```

#### Explanation

We know that `Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager` will be resolved automatically if we run `Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider`. See:

```
Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider@registerAuthenticator
```

So, we must run this service provider before we want to use `AuthManager`. But Lumen is slightly different. I see that `Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager` isn't registered yet in:

```
Laravel\Lumen\Application::$availableBindings
```

Which is it's a hack to make Lumen run faster when the container wants to resolved the resource, see:

```
Laravel\Lumen\Application@make
```

So, basically, if you want to resolve `Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager` class and it's dependency, you may register it's class bindings first before you use it.

#### Update

We know that

```
Laravel\Lumen\Application::$availableBindings
```

property is in `public` visibility, so this works too:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Service Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will register all of the application's service providers which
| are used to bind services into the container. Service providers are
| totally optional, so you are not required to uncomment this line.
|
*/

$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);

$app->availableBindings['Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager'] = 'registerAuthBindings';
$app->alias('auth', 'Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager');
```

#### Update 2

I understand that there's lot of problems if we want to implements JWT Authentication in Lumen with [this library](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth). So, I make a bootstrapped (clean start) Lumen Application that integrated well with this library. Please check out [my repo](https://github.com/krisanalfa/lumen-jwt). I'll add explanation about which one and why we should change the code later. Cheers.

Comment: $app->singleton(Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::class, means when ever the AuthManager is used, it will use the same instance, but can you please explain the code $app->make('auth') ?

Comment: Hi @simo, I updated the answer. Is it clear enough? Just tell me when you need more clear explanation, I'll help you to dig deeper into Lumen kernel if you want.

Comment: Thanks Krisa very much for explanation, I will try the solution once I reach the office, I am very experienced with OOP, but needs to learn more on Laravel and lumen frameworks.. Could not find good resources on the architecture for them..

Comment: Thanks Krisan, it worked, I didn't get the error message correctly, I thought that AuthManager was resolved, but $app var was not injected into it..

Comment: @simo Glad to help you, Sir

Comment: Thanks @Krisan , I have put your solution at the issue in the repo's issue, but I still have an issue there https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/561 , I added it there sense its a repo related issue.. do you know how to solve it too?

Comment: Hi @simo, I updated the answer. Sorry for the late reply, I just arrived at home. If you need something, you can contact me in my email. I really glad to help people.

Comment: Thanks @Krisan, I will test your repo soon, very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this with `SessionManager` with the same unresolvable `$app` variable when registering the existing Laravel `SessionServiceProvider`.

After reading @krisanalfa's answer, I tried to peek at the values of `$availableBindings` which can be found in `Application.php` and it looks like this:

```
public $availableBindings = [
      'auth' => 'registerAuthBindings',
      'auth.driver' => 'registerAuthBindings',
      'Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager' => 'registerAuthBindings',

      'Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Factory' => 'registerCacheBindings',
      'Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository' => 'registerCacheBindings',
      ....
];
```

The value of each keys represents the methods that is going to be used to load the implementations which is also inside the `Application.php`.

If you need to load the configuration and register the binding:

```
protected function registerAuthBindings()
{
    $this->singleton('auth', function () {
        return $this->loadComponent('auth', 'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider', 'auth');
    });

    $this->singleton('auth.driver', function () {
        return $this->loadComponent('auth', 'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider', 'auth.driver');
    });

   ...
}
```

But if the service doesn't need any configuration, you just register it like:

```
protected function registerEventBindings()
{
    $this->singleton('events', function () {
        $this->register('Illuminate\Events\EventServiceProvider');

        return $this->make('events');
    });
}
```

Source at the time of this writing: https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.8/src/Application.php

Hope this helps others in the future. This took me lots of hours.