# Enabling session in lumen framework

Tags: laravel, microservices, lumen

I have two (but let's image more) micro-services (API) which need to be aware of authenticated user. Ideally I would simple like to resume their sessions.

All micro-services are using same storage for sessions: redis.

All API calls will have Cookie header, so all services will be able to resume sessions based on that cookie. I have successfully implemented this via PHP $_SESSIONs.

Now the question: how would you go about implementing this with Laravel/Lumen?

Comment: Too broad, primarily opinion-based question. There are many ways to do that. For example, using a "cache server" for session storage, like redis.

Comment: are you using any API Gateway for authentication or you haven't started implementation. ?

Comment: I recently worked on Microservices, We were using Kong as our API Gateway to attach auth headers, and then each MicroService will receive these details and will get a user either from Redis or any db

Comment: @rummykhan considering AWS API Gateway. My concerns are the fact that Laravel has session and Lumen has not.

Comment: @rock3t, I totally respect your opinion but why do you need sessions at all in microservice, I'm still lost.

Comment: But even if you do, You can still use php native sessions.

Comment: @rummykhan you right, there's a reason why Lumen has no session and token based authentication. I was still interested to see if anyone will come forward with suggestion. As far as my implementation goes it's Cokkie header and resuming native PHP $_SESSIONs. I was mainly interested to see if some one came up with Middleware or any other solution to cover this use-case.

Comment: @rock3t, I'm glad you asked. I was also thinking of enabling these for lumen, I'm testing it and I'll post as answer if it succeeded or not.

Comment: Well I've tried, You cannot use `illuminate/session` in lumen 5.2 and after, because now some classes in `illuminate/session` depends on `Illuminate/Foundation/Application` and not on `Illuminate/Contracts/Container` which is making them un-usable for lumen.

Comment: Your question is legit, I've upvoted it.

Comment: Thanks @rummykhan for giving it a go. I'll probably will authenticate API calls via tokens for now and then see where projects takes me. Plain PHP $_SESSION are always an option. Put an answer together with your research and PHP nataive SESSIONS and I'll chose it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157993/discussion-between-rummykhan-and-rock3t).

Comment: The following link is the life saver.
[here](http://blog.tegimus.com/2018/08/09/add-session-and-csrf-protection-to-lumen-application/#comment-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer is outdated.

I answered and explained a bit how to properly do it in my answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55227723/10975709)

I also posted what is the problem on my question at [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/lumen-middleware-priority?reply=499390)

To quote:

> the solution that is found in the link you gave is that, first it tells you to manually register the `SessionManager` to prevent the `unresolvable depedency parameter #0 $app` then also register the existing `SessionServiceProvider` which also binds another instance `SessionManager`.
>
> Problem with that is, some components use the other instance and other parts use the new one which causes my auth `attempt` session not being save despite actually being `put` inside.

Answer (score 73):

**Last update on 5th of March 2021**

(This answer was getting a lot of attention from Laravel community so I thought of updating it.)

Laravel has officially stopped supporting sessions & views in `laravel/lumen` framework from version 5.2 and on wards.

But `laravel` still have a component `illuminate/session` which can be installed in `lumen/framework` and we can play around with this.

**Step - 1**

install `illuminate/session` using

`composer require illuminate/session`

**Step - 2**

Now goto `bootstrap/app.php` and add this middleware

```php
$app->middleware([
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
]);
```

Purpose of adding the above middleware is to start session on every request and save session before serving response.

**Step - 3**

Now add `config/session.php`, since it is not present in `Lumen` by default. You can take `session.php` from [Laravel official repo](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/session.php).

**Step - 4**

Create framework session storage directory by

```sh
mkdir -p storage/framework/sessions
```

Thanks to [DayDream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50080632/2190807)

**Step - 5**

In `bootstrap/app.php` add bindings for `\Illuminate\Session\SessionManager`

```php
$app->singleton(Illuminate\Session\SessionManager::class, function () use ($app) {
    return $app->loadComponent('session', Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class, 'session');
});

$app->singleton('session.store', function () use ($app) {
    return $app->loadComponent('session', Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class, 'session.store');
});
```

Thanks to [@xxRockOnxx](https://laracasts.com/@xxRockOnxx) for finding `loadComponent` method.
It takes 3 arguments,

- first one is `config` file name. (file should be present in `config/` directory)
- second is ServiceProvider FQN
- third is return of this method.

`loadComponent` just calls the `$app->register` and inject `$app` while building the `ServiceProvider`

**How to Use**

```
// Save Session
$router->get('/', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {

    $request->session()->put('name', 'Lumen-Session');

    return response()->json([
        'session.name' => $request->session()->get('name')
    ]);
});


// Test session
$router->get('/session', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {

    return response()->json([
        'session.name' => $request->session()->get('name'),
    ]);
});
```

I've also added example over github supporting from lumen framework v5.6 to all the way to current version v8.0.

https://github.com/rummykhan/lumen-session-example

Comment: Thank you so much. This was very helpful

Comment: However the Redirector (for example when using redirect()) session does not get set, it is always null. I can see the session object set on Request object so I am able to use view()->with() properly but if i use redirect()->with() it fails due to session object being null on the redirector

Comment: when i do that i get : Session store not set on request.

Comment: On Step 4, you'll probably want to add a `.gitignore` file - https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/storage/framework/sessions/.gitignore

Comment: it is creating session for every new request and i can check my sessions dir it has lot of files generated. is it not causing the memory issue after some days/months time..?

Answer (score 6):

It is important to that you also use `$request->session()`, otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the solution mentioned above, however, it's also required to create a folder `storage/framework/sessions` if using the default settings.