# Redirect with parameters Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I want to make redirect with parameters in Lumen (as laravel). 
For example. It working in laravel
laravel:

```
return redirect()->route("main")->with("success", "Success!");
```

Blade:

```
<h4 class="text-center" >{{ session('success')  }} </h4>
```

In lumen doesn't exists **"with()"** but i know that via `headers` can do it 
In advance thanks for help.

Comment: You should consider to move to Laravel framework, the `with()` uses flash sessions, which are no longer supported in Lumen >= 5.2

Comment: Try add session handler manually
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47055083/6548457

Comment: i have a small project therefore i decided to use lumen.. unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Lumen dropped `session` support in past few versions. 
If you want, you can use Laravel `session` package or simply manually set PHP session ex: `$_SESSION['success']['Success!']` and then retrieve it `{{ $_SESSION['success'] }}`.

Answer for Laravel session package [https://stackoverflow.com/a/47055083/9851907]