# Lumen 5.6: Alternative for session

Tags: php, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

Am trying to build secure login for my small app so i decided to use JWT approach by using JWT firebase library for lumen, 
i discover i cant revoke my token except some dynamic data like session. And Lumen has stop shipping with session package since lumen 5.2, 
i know there might be a reason why they stop supporting session .

And i have Tymon JWT package but it does not work well with lumen 5.6.
That why i use Firebase JWT-PHP as alternative 

I will like to know alternative for session with strong example or any idea of best JWT login with revoke of token on logout

Comment: They stopped supporting sessions because Lumen is focusing on stateless APIs. Why do you use JWT instead of Lumen?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use sessions, the method in this comment seemed to do the trick, though I haven't torture-tested it all that much (I just discovered it a couple days ago myself), so YMMV:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47055083/1246105

In short, you can just ala-carte install the session-handling from Laravel.